# Datepicker does not close on clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this javascript code to use hijri date picker but when I open datepicker and than click out the div or on body my datepiker did not close. Can any one help to close datepicker when I click out side. I need to correct this code and hide calendar when I will click outside the calendar or body .

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Health Athority</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/calendar.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/hijri-date.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js_clander.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .my_row{
  
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
 }
#testme{
width:400px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
</style>

</head>

<div id="testme">
<div id="datepicker"><input id="picked-text" type="text" size="35"/><input id="pick-button" type="button" onclick="pickADate();" value="pick"/></div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var pickedTxt = document.getElementById('picked-text'),
        pickBtn = document.getElementById('pick-button'),
        datepicker = new Calendar();
    document.getElementById('datepicker').appendChild(datepicker.getElement());
    datepicker.getElement().style.marginTop = '10px';

    datepicker.callback = function() {
        pickedTxt.value = datepicker.getDate().getDateString();
        pickedTxt.selectionStart = 0;
        pickedTxt.selectionEnd = pickedTxt.value.length;
        pickedTxt.focus();
    };

    datepicker.onHide = function() {
        pickBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    };
 
    function pickADate() {
        pickBtn.style.display = 'none';
        datepicker.show();
    }

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Example is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems not working, all that you want is to close picker when you click on body that you can achieve it by Jquery **focusout** function.

```
$('#datepicker').on('focusout', function(){
$('YourDatePickerID').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working..

You are missing closing `</script>` here:

```
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Example:**

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Health Athority</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/calendar.css"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/hijri-date.js"></script>
     <script src='https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/hijri-date.js'></script><script src='https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/calendar.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     .my_row{
      
      margin-top: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
     }
    #testme{
    width:400px;
        border: 3px solid blue;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <div id="testme">
    <div id="datepicker"><input id="picked-text" type="text" size="35"/><input id="pick-button" type="button" onclick="pickADate();" value="pick"/></div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var pickedTxt = document.getElementById('picked-text'),
            pickBtn = document.getElementById('pick-button'),
            datepicker = new Calendar();
        document.getElementById('datepicker').appendChild(datepicker.getElement());
        datepicker.getElement().style.marginTop = '10px';

        datepicker.callback = function() {
            pickedTxt.value = datepicker.getDate().getDateString();
            pickedTxt.selectionStart = 0;
            pickedTxt.selectionEnd = pickedTxt.value.length;
            pickedTxt.focus();
        };

        datepicker.onHide = function() {
            pickBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
        };
     
        function pickADate() {
            pickBtn.style.display = 'none';
            datepicker.show();
        }
  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below code to your script

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var popup = $("#pick-button");
    if(!($('#pick-button').is(e.target)) && (!$(".header-button").is(e.target))&&(!$(".setting-button").is(e.target))) {
        datepicker.hide();
        pickBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
});
```

```js
var pickedTxt = document.getElementById('picked-text'),
        pickBtn = document.getElementById('pick-button'),
        datepicker = new Calendar();
    document.getElementById('datepicker').appendChild(datepicker.getElement());
    datepicker.getElement().style.marginTop = '10px';

    datepicker.callback = function() {
        pickedTxt.value = datepicker.getDate().getDateString();
        pickedTxt.selectionStart = 0;
        pickedTxt.selectionEnd = pickedTxt.value.length;
        pickedTxt.focus();
    };

    datepicker.onHide = function() {
        pickBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    };
 
    function pickADate() {
        pickBtn.style.display = 'none';
        datepicker.show();
    }
       $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var popup = $("#pick-button");
        if (!($('#pick-button').is(e.target))&&(!$(".header-button").is(e.target))&&(!$(".setting-button").is(e.target))) {
            datepicker.hide();
             pickBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Health Athority</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/calendar.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ZulNs.github.io/libs/hijri-date.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://zulns.github.io/libs/calendar.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .my_row{
  
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
 }
#testme{
width:400px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="testme">
<div id="datepicker"><input id="picked-text" type="text" size="35"/><input id="pick-button" type="button" onclick="pickADate();" value="pick"/></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Najeeb satti IF ANY DOUBT LET ME KNOW

Comment: Hello Dhaarani now it's working fine and i add my project . i spend one day full to hide this date picker . what i had not success to hide this. i try your code and add my project it's very helpfull to me . thanks so much .

Comment: @Najeeb satti if my answer is usefull to you accept my answer.